# Need to move files to specific directory based on last two characters of filename in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

Please forgive my ignorance. I'm sure this is very basic, but I am so new to Bash. Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

I have a series of files (within a source directory) that I need to organize into other specific directories based on the last two charcters of their name. e.g. K1F2P4T1, needs to go to one directory while K1F2P4R1 needs to go to another. What I need it to do is check all files for the last two characters and if it ends with, e.g T1, E1, or B1 it goes to one directory and if it ends in C1, M1, or Z1 it gets moved to another.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
mv *{T1,E1,B1} one_dir
mv *{C1,M1,Z1} another_dir
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!